# How to solve time out error in selenium webdriver with java?

Tags: java, selenium, timeoutexception

My Html

```
<form id="load_form" class="ajaxsubmit" method="post" action="ajax.php">
<input type="hidden" value="register" name="action">
<h3>Registration Form</h3>
<img id="loader" width="20" height="20" style="display:none;" src="images/loader.gif">
<p id="alert"></p>
<fieldset>
<fieldset>
<fieldset>
<fieldset>
<fieldset>
<fieldset>
<label>Username:</label>
<input type="text" required="" name="username">
</fieldset>
```

My Java Code

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//input[@name='username']")));
element.sendKeys("john");
```

Getting Below Error

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed
>   out after 30 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by
>   By.xpath: //input[@name='username'] Build info: version: '2.53.0',
>   revision: '35ae25b', time: '2016-03-15 17:01:03'

Any Help? I have already tried by increasing wait but doesn't work

Comment: I think this `input` is inside an iframe or frame, please check it first and let me know..

Comment: No it's not under Iframe or frame.

Comment: How do you know it's not under Iframe or frame???

Comment: Go to browser console by pressing `f12` and execute these `document.getElementsByTagName("frame")` and `document.getElementsByTagName("iframe")`.. and let me know what is the result for both...

Comment: Beacuse there are other textbox present in same page and i am able to insert the values in them but not in Username and Password field. I think it may be "display:none"

Comment: But in your provided HTML, there is no style property append into input as `display:none`...??

Comment: refer this link http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/index.php

Comment: Ok are you looking for open popup form??

Comment: yes i am half done

Comment: are you sure that the popup is opened?

Comment: @Mesut Güneş yes it is open and i am able to insert values upto "city" and then i am stuck

Comment: Got it, actually there are two elements with same name where one is hidden and one is visible and you are intracting with first one that's why are unable to locate, try using `cssSelector`, see below provided answer..:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually [there are](http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/index.php) two `input` elements present with the same name `username` where one is hidden and another is visible and you are intracting with first one which is not visible on the page that's why you are unable to locate, try using `cssSelector` as below :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);

WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("div#load_box input[name = 'username']")));
element.sendKeys("john");
```

Comment: This is correct but when I tried with Xpath it doesn't work and works fine with Css Selector so can we say Css selector are superior than Xpath? because  by this query //input[@name='username'] only one element found?

Comment: Actually it's true that `cssSelector` is much faster than `xpath`, but `xpath` is also a powerful because many cases `cssSelector` doesn't work but `xpath` works in every case...No, `//input[@name='username']` xpath locates two element, verify again at browser console using this `$x("//input[@name='username']")`..it returns two elements, problem not with `xpath`, problem with finding element with selenium because selenium always returns first element in order if locators same for multiple element and unfortunately in elements order invisible element is first..

Comment: @Ab123 If would like to use `xpath`, you can use `//div[@id = 'load_box']//input[@name = 'username']` xpath, it will returns desire unique element...:)