# Timed out exception when I try to logout

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, explicit

I have to login yahoomail and then I have to compose mail and then i have to logout. 
Am able to login ,compose but am unable to logout. Please find below the code for the same.
I need to do it through explicit wait.

```
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver,30);
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-username")).sendKeys("****");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-signin")).click();
//  WebElement password=driver.findElement(By.id("login-passwd"));

    WebElement element=wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("login-passwd")));
    element.sendKeys("*****");
    driver.findElement(By.id("login-signin")).click();
    String text=element.getText();

    WebDriverWait wait1=new WebDriverWait(driver, 20);
    WebElement element4=wait1.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("yucs-mail_link_id")));
    element4.click();

    WebDriverWait wait2=new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);

    WebElement element3=wait2.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-compose']")));
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@class='btn btn-compose']")).click();
    //element3.click();


    WebDriverWait wait3=new WebDriverWait(driver, 300);
    WebElement element5=wait3.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("to-field")));
    element5.sendKeys("****");
    driver.findElement(By.id("subject-field")).sendKeys("Test mail");
    driver.findElement(By.id("rtetext")).sendKeys("Hi ,congrates");
    driver.findElement(By.linkText("Send")).click(); //("yui_3_16_0_ym19_1_1487880655873_2622")).click();

    Actions builder=new Actions(driver);
    WebElement logout=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[@id='yucs-profile']/a/i")); //yui_3_16_0_2_1487938370596_76 //.//*[@id='yui_3_10_3_1_1375219693637_127']
    builder.clickAndHold(logout).click().build().perform();     


    WebDriverWait wait4=new WebDriverWait(driver, 30);
    WebElement element9=wait4.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("yucs-signout")));
    element9.click();
```

Comment: [References](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38910232/how-to-solve-time-out-error-in-selenium-webdriver-with-java)

Comment: I didnt find any refernce for logout from yahoo mail

Comment: are you able to find the "logout "  path/id ?

Comment: yes am able to find id and xpath both

Comment: can you try by increasing  the time out option ?

Comment: I already tried by increasing the time but its of no use

Comment: [Tried] (http://corejavawithselenium.blogspot.in/2016/10/yahoo-mail-sign-out-code-selenium.html)